# How do I escape _ in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to escape the underscore character in a `LIKE` Statement. I have tried to use the `ESCAPE` keyword as follows:

```
COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE '%[\_]xyz%' ESCAPE '\'
```

but it doesn't work. It is still filtering out `%xyz%` when I really want it to filter out `%_xyz%`.

If not by the `ESCAPE` keyword, how else can this be accomplished?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just this should work:

```
COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE '%[_]xyz%'
```

You don't need the ESCAPE here. What you wrote should also work.

If you do want to use ESCAPE you could do this:

```
columnname NOT LIKE '%\_xyz%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Documentation on escape characters is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am not sure why it wasn't working before but it does now so much appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

use brakets [_]

This works for me in SQL Server 2005

```
select *
from #table 
where a like '%[_]xyz%'
```

Comment: +1: Supporting link: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 5):

Try it without the brackets:

```
COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE '%\_xyz%' ESCAPE '\'
```